# Add new row with result of sum from other rows with Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
  familia              n
   <chr>            <int>
 1 Hylidae            885
 2 Leptodactylidae    276
 3 Bufonidae          111
 4 Craugastoridae      99
 5 NA                  89
 6 Odontophrynidae     72
 7 Brachycephalidae    55
 8 Phyllomedusidae     55
 9 Microhylidae        45
10 Ceratophryidae      20
```

I would like to sum the rows with n < 100 and create a new row with the sum result like:

```
11 Families < 100 counts XX
```

XX being the result of the sum of the rows. How can I do that with Dplyr? I tried some solutions that I found here that were close to my particular case, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `add_row` from `tibble`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>% 
   add_row(familia = 'Families < 100', n = sum(.$n[.$n < 100]))
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   familia              n
#   <chr>            <int>
# 1 Hylidae            885
# 2 Leptodactylidae    276
# 3 Bufonidae          111
# 4 Craugastoridae      99
# 5 <NA>                89
# 6 Odontophrynidae     72
# 7 Brachycephalidae    55
# 8 Phyllomedusidae     55
# 9 Microhylidae        45
#10 Ceratophryidae      20
#11 Families < 100     435
```

---

Or another option using only `dplyr` is to `filter` the rows where 'n' is less than 100, get the `sum` in `summarise` and then bind the rows with the original data

```
df1 %>%
   filter(n < 100) %>% 
   summarise(familia = "Families < 100", n = sum(n)) %>% 
   bind_rows(df1, .)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(familia = c("Hylidae", "Leptodactylidae", "Bufonidae", 
"Craugastoridae", NA, "Odontophrynidae", "Brachycephalidae", 
"Phyllomedusidae", "Microhylidae", "Ceratophryidae"), n = c(885L, 
276L, 111L, 99L, 89L, 72L, 55L, 55L, 45L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```